# What is the derivative of $|f(x)|^n$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, absolute-value

Well, it's time for a trivial question but I really need a clarification about!

Let's say I have to evaluate

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\ |f(x)|^n$$

Shall I have to reason by treating the function as

$$|f(x)|^n = \left(\sqrt{f(x)^2}\right)^n$$

and then it would be quite easy, or shall I try to apply, somehow, the same rule for the derivative of $|x|$ like?

$$D\ |f(x)|^n = n\ f(x)^{n-1}\frac{|f(x)|}{f(x)}f'(x) = n\ f(x)^{n-2}|f(x)|f'(x)$$

Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: If radical  is never the negative root but always the positive or zero root.  The derivative of thar square root of f squared is not as easy as you think it will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest issue is that the function $y \mapsto |y| = \sqrt{y^2}$ is of course not differentiable when $y = 0$. Given this, we can only take the derivative of $|f(x)|^n$ on all points where $f(x) \ne 0$.

But as long as we are at $x$ where $f(x) \ne 0$, **either of your two proposed methods will work.** We have on the one hand
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} |f(x)|^n
&= \frac{d}{dx} [f(x)^2]^{n/2} \\
&= \frac{n}{2} [f(x)^2]^{\left(\tfrac{n}{2} - 1\right)} \left[2f(x)f'(x)\right]. \\
&= n \cdot f(x) \cdot f'(x) \cdot |f(x)|^{n-2}
\end{align*}
and on the other hand
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} |f(x)|^n
&= n |f(x)|^{n-1} \left[\frac{d}{dx} |f(x)|\right] \\
&= n |f(x)|^{n-1} \frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|} f'(x) \\
&= n \cdot f(x) \cdot f'(x) \cdot |f(x)|^{n-2}.
\end{align*}
where we used $\frac{d}{dy} |y| = \frac{y}{|y|}$.

You can now see that these two expressions are the same.

**Note 1:** In your calculations, I saw a couple of small typos or errors.

**Note 2:**
We have to be careful dealing with the expression $[f(x)^2]^{n/2}$. Note this is **not** the same as $f(x)^n$. For a potentially negative $a$, we do not have that $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I notices an error too in what I wrote, and I was going to edit. Thank you again!

Comment: @FourierTransform You're welcome, and nice question.

Answer (score 5):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\abs}{abs}$If $n$ is an even integer, you may as well write
$$
|f(x)|^{n} = f(x)^{n}
$$
and differentiate using the chain rule.

Otherwise, if $x \neq 0$, the function $\abs(x) = |x|$ is differentiable at $x$, and
$$
\abs'(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}.
$$
This (plus the chain rule) guarantees that if $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f(x) \neq 0$, then your formula is correct:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} |f(x)|^{n} = n\, f(x)^{n-2} |f(x)|\, f'(x).
$$
If $f(x) = 0$ (or if $f$ is not differentiable at $x$), you need to examine the specific form of $f$ to determine whether or not $\abs^{n}(f)(x) = |f(x)|^{n}$ is differentiable at $x$.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I forgot about the case $n = $ even, it would make things easier. Even if actually it was really a general case then one in which I was interested. +1